# How to use a 3rd (and 4th) level chooser in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xfce

I would like to use the Caps Lock key (They key I never used) for me 3rd level chooser key.  I have managed to get it to act as a compose key but from what I have heard (correct me if I am wrong) the 3rd level chooser acts kind of like another shift while the compose key requires memorized key combinations.  How can I have the Caps Lock key be the 3rd level chooser (and Shift+Caps Lock be the 4th level chooser) in the XFCE desktop environment (using XFCE settings manager).  I have found instructions for DEs like Gnome and KDE but not for XFCE.  Most of those guides detailed using the settings managers relating to those desktop environments.